# What do I need to make my Ethernet-connectible printer accessible by wireless?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printer, ethernet

I use a 802.11 wireless network. I have a printer which has an RJ-45 Ethernet port, which is no physically close to to anything like a Wireless-to-Ethernet router.

I would like to add as little hardware as possible to make my printer visible on the network.

I *think* what I need is one of the following:

- Some sort of mini Ethernet-Wireless router, with reduced functionality allowing for a small form factor and low power consumption.
- An Ethernet link simulator over radio: The printer will think it's connected by cable to the router, but in fact in the middle there'll be two devices, converting Ethernet packets to radio signals or vice versa, which only communicate with each other (and don't necessarily communicate using 802.11).

But I'm not entirely sure what I need, and more importantly, how these devices are called.

**Note:**

- I'm not asking for recommendations of specific products to purchase.
- I see there are several related questions, so maybe this is a dupe, but I couldn't quite figure out if what I asked about has a proper answer in any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a wireless router that has "repeater" mode. This will allow it to be a client on a wireless network and pass that network on to devices plugged into it's wired ports.

I currently use an ASUS RT-N12 router to do the same thing for a person on a terminal computer and a printer. That might be over-kill for just a printer though since it's wirelss N and gigabit speeds.

Answer (score 0):

You need a wireless bridge like the Linksys [WET54g](http://support.linksys.com/en-us/support/bridges/WET54G).

[Using the Wireless-G Bridge as an external wireless adapter](http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=4902)

Answer (score 0):

Just look for a wireless access point (AP) that has "Client mode".

Commonly an Access Point is connected to ethernet to provide other devices with wireless access on that network.

An Access Point in client mode does the opposite of that, it connects to a wireless network as a client and provides means to connect a hardwire device such as your printer.